# Cannot get Cordova project building in VS2015 when add crosswalk web plugin

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to add sqlite plugin in my cordova App using Visual studio 2015 but it's display classNotFound Error so I add Crosswalk WebView Engine plugin but now i can't able to build the project. I removed crosswalk plugin still same build issue. Please help me.

```
  ------ Build configuration options: --debug
1>  Running command: cmd "/s /c "E:\Krishna\MyLimo247\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat --debug --buildConfig=E:\Krishna\MyLimo247\build.json""
1>  ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
1>  JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55
1>  Reading build config file: E:\Krishna\MyLimo247\build.json
1>  E:\Krishna\MyLimo247\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
1>                      throw e;
1>                            ^
1>  SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
1>      at Object.parse (native)
1>      at parseOpts (E:\Krishna\MyLimo247\platforms\android\cordova\lib\build.js:501:27)
1>      at Object.module.exports.run (E:\Krishna\MyLimo247\platforms\android\cordova\lib\build.js:559:16)
1>      at E:\Krishna\MyLimo247\platforms\android\cordova\build:36:22
1>      at _fulfilled (E:\Krishna\MyLimo247\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:798:54)
1>      at self.promiseDispatch.done (E:\Krishna\MyLimo247\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:827:30)
1>      at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (E:\Krishna\MyLimo247\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:760:13)
1>      at E:\Krishna\MyLimo247\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:574:44
1>      at flush (E:\Krishna\MyLimo247\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
1>      at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
1>  Command finished with error code 1: cmd /s /c "E:\Krishna\MyLimo247\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat --debug --buildConfig=E:\Krishna\MyLimo247\build.json"
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error BLD106: Command finished with error code 1: cmd /s /c "E:\Krishna\MyLimo247\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat --debug --buildConfig=E:\Krishna\MyLimo247\build.json" ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
1>  You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
1>MDAVSCLI : error : cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: The "E:\Krishna\MyLimo247\build.json" file might be damaged. Open it and see if everything inside is in good JSON format. Try replacing this file from a fresh blank project.(better clear the cache before creating new project)

Comment: Yeah. Thanks @ElvisXia. I solved it. It's problem of cache